# Trim exception message

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to trim an exception message with the below code:

```
Response.Redirect("IllegalCharactersError.aspx?error=");
string message = ex.Message;
string cleanMessage = message.Substring(message.IndexOf("=") + 1);
Session.Add("IllegalCharactersError", cleanMessage.Replace("\\", ""));
```

Here is a sample of the string:
A potentially dangerous `Request.Form` value was detected from the client

```
(ctl00$Main$EmployerRegistrationCtrl$CompanyDetails$CompanyTradingAs="'<'My Company Trading").
```

I only want to display `'<'My Company Trading` but my label is displaying `\"'<'My Company Trading\").` with back slashes so its not displaying and I cant seem to remove, any ideads how to acheive this?

Thanks
Darren

Comment: Are those backslashes in the label on the asp.net page, or in the debugger? The latter tries to display a string in a format that you could use in code: with escaped quotes. So then those backslashes aren't really in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx):

```
lbl.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value);
```

Use [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) to read the `Text` of the label later:

```
string value = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(lbl.Text);
```

If you want to transfer the error-message via URL, you need [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) and later [HttpUtility.UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy.aspx).

But i'm not sure where you are getting the backslashes from. The original error-message has none, are you masking it somewhere?

For the sake of completeness, here you find informations how you prevent the "dangerous `Request.Form` value"-error: [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Comment: No, not at this point. HTML encoding should be done at the point where the text is really *inserted* into the HTML context, not at arbitrary places.

Comment: @Roland: He is showing the text in an ASP.NET Label. Isn't that a point where text is *inserted* into the HTML context?!

Comment: Yes, it is. I only concentrated on the larger block of code from the question, and in that code I didn't see any need for encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make the `IllegalCharactersException` (or however it is called in your example) yourself? If you did, you should add some useful properties to it:

```
ex.OffendingValue
ex.Field
```

These properties should be filles when the exception is thrown.

That saves you from parsing the string at all.

Comment: The IllegalCharactersException is just a page I redirect to, Im using HttpRequestValidationException, I would be interested in how you would create your own exeption with those properties though. Thanks

Comment: I just read the documentation for `HttpRequestValidationException`, and it didn't sound as if there were additional useful data besides the `ex.Message`. You might have a look at `ex.Data`, and if there is nothing useful in it, parsing the message is the way to go.